# Spring Boot @Configuration bean name conflicts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a project with lot of small libraries that define beans with @Configuration classes (Spring Integration and Spring Batch stuff) and I often encounter problems because both libraries have a bean with the same name.

It is possible to either:

- Apply a prefix to all the beans of a configuration classes
- Force the application to crash at startup if two beans exists with the same name
- Use another solution that would fix it without a redesign of the application

Comment: For libraries, Spring Boot's AutoConfiguration is more preferable than `@Configuraiton`s to be component-scanned or imported in. And the AutoConfiguration bean name is by default the fully-qualified name of class that do not clash.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I don't see how I should use AutoConfiguration to create customs Spring Integration ServiceActivators or Spring Batch Steps.

Comment: For 1, you can register your own `BeanNameGenerator` to SpringApplication using [`SpringApplicationBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html).
BTW, AutoConfigurations are plain `@Configuration`s which are loaded by Spring Boot's `@EnableAutoConfigurtion` by looking up `META-INF/spring.factories` and usually have `@ConditionOn*` on it and with `@ConfigurationProperties` for easier customization.

Comment: The simple and dirty way would be @Bean(name = "fooBean") and you add the appropriate prefix to each Bean name per library as you see fit.  If I come up with anything else, I'll reply back.

Answer (score -1):

I understand you mean that you have two beans called the same with the @Configuration annotation, this collides and does not work with the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lapeira.formacion.CasoFinalApplication]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'configuracion' for bean class [com.lapeira.formacion.seguridad.Configuracion] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.lapeira.formacion.batch.Configuracion]
```

Just rename one of the two classes and it should work.

Comment: If it is external dependencies that is not possible you need to have controll to do that